# Upload video on server in swift

Tags: ios, swift, video

I am trying to upload video on server in swift. I am uploading both image and video with some more parameters. I am able to upload image on server but not to upload video. My server could not find my attached video in request and gives null pointer exception on server side. I am new in swift, please help me to upload video on server.

```
func createBodyWithParametersvideo(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, videoDataKey : NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
    var body = NSMutableData();

    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }

    var  filename = "forest.jpg"
    var mimetype = "image/jpg"

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"thumbnail\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendData(imageDataKey)
    body.appendString("\r\n")
    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

    print("video data lenght is :- \(videoDataKey.length)")

    filename = "video.mp4"
    mimetype = "video/mp4"
    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"; filename=\"video.mp4\"\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendData(videoDataKey)
    body.appendString("\r\n")
    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")


    return body
}
```

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this line

```
body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
```

that goes before

```
print("video data lenght is :- \(videoDataKey.length)")
```

in your code.

It is a type of separator in POST body that should start and end.

```
// 1st parametr
body.appendString("--\(bound)\r\n") // START PART
/*Your post parametrs*/
body.appendString("\r\n")
...
// N-th parametr
body.appendString("--\(bound)\r\n") // START PART
/*Your post parametrs*/
body.appendString("\r\n")

body.appendString("--\(bound)--\r\n") // CLOSE
```